# Can I use Google Apps as a mail service to send registration, confirmation, marketing emails?

Tags: gmail, google-workspace

I'm developing a web application. It has authentication system, that is users have to confirm their email on registration, password/email/profile changes, etc. I'm considering mail services for this purpose, Amazon SES (Simple Email Service), for example.

But I'd like to know may I use somehow Google Apps for it?

I have a paid account in Google Apps, it is linked to my app's domain name. So it would be convenient for me to use Google Apps as a mail service.

Does it offer something similar to Amazon SES, MailChimp, Mailgun, SendGrid, others?

Answer (score 2):

No, Google Apps does not include a mass mailing or marketing tool. Google Apps accounts are subject to both [sending](https://support.google.com/a/answer/166852?hl=en) and [receiving](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1366776?hl=en) limits. If you can stay within these limits you, or a 3rd party, could build a tool using Apps Script, Gmail, and Sheets in Google Apps.

When paying for some of the other services you mentioned you are also getting their expertise, and knowledge on how to successfully execute your goals while still staying compliant with laws, rules, and regulations around mass emails. Google Apps does not provide any of these.